# generate a tree-like hierarchy based on the headings in a word document, relative to a particular heading

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I sometimes have to write proposals on the specifications of a project, most of the times a website.  I like to include an 'outline' section which is basically a tree-like hierarchy of all the sections of the website.  These correspond almost one-to-one with a heading.  Imagine the below heading structure in a document.

```
Project
Revision History
Table of Contents
Project Outline
Project Information
    Homepage
        Interactive Banner
        Various Panels
        Search
        Login
    Common Components
        Current Weather
        Social Networking Icons
        Contact Details
        Live Chat
    Content Pages
        Gallery
        Comments
    Contact Us
```

In the **Project Outline** section, I then create a *SmartArt > Horizontal Hierarchy* control, and fill it with basically almost the same content under the **Project Information** heading.  See the below attached imaged to get an idea of how it would look.

[image: Image showing hierarchy of project outline, related to document structure above]

I said *almost* the same content, because I add sometimes to it, like there is in the image do under **Various Panels**, where there are no actual headings for them but are shown in the outline.

The problem is that by time if the proposal goes through various iterations, it is a headache to have to manually update this hierarchy myself, given that it is based mainly on the headings.  Is there any way something similar can be auto-generated from the document itself, saying you would choose **Project Information** as the relevant node, and it's children are generated as a tree, and still allowing you to add custom nodes where you want?

Comment: A macro is probably the only way forward to achieve this. Have a Google and play with the API.

Comment: So you're still here, but you gave up? A pity.

Comment: Some of what you want to do with build-in heading styles might be done by importing into PowerPoint. http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/usebuiltinheadingstyles.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following macro. It assumes that your headings are paragraphs that use the standard Heading Styles (otherwise, it becomes a lot harder to achieve AFAICS). It will try to do something sensible if your Heading levels are not a strict hierarchy, but it's up to you to fix up the macro as required.

Backup your document.

Modify the sub "testMakeHierarchy" to look for the Heading text that indicates the heading subtree you want to use. Then in the document, click where you want the diagram, then run the macro.

If you already have a diagram then I suggest you click next to the existing diagram, run the macro, then delete the old diagram if you no longer need it.

```
Sub testMakeHierarchy()
' change the text "Project Information" as appropriate
' Click where you want the diagram
' then run this sub.
Call makeHierarchy(Selection.Range, _
  "urn:microsoft.com/office/officeart/2005/8/layout/hierarchy2", _
  "Project Information")
End Sub

Sub makeHierarchy(rngLocation As Word.Range, strLayout As String, strTopLevelText As String)
' Inserts a Hierarchy SmartArt diagram
' - at the location specified by rngLocation,
' - using the SmartArtLayout defined by strLayout
' - taking text from all the Heading n paragraph styles
'    from the Heading paragraph with text strTopLevelText
'    to the next Heading paragraph with the same level
'    or the end of document
'    strMatchHeadingStyle is a string used to match styles - see testMakeHierarchy for an example.

' Currently makes a number of kludgy assumptions, the main one being that
' if (say) the starting point is a Heading 2 paragraph, the next para will be Heading 3
Const theFontName As String = "Arial"
Const thePlaceholderText As String = "[Placeholder]"
Dim bContinue As Boolean
Dim bDiagramCreated As Boolean
Dim intLevel As Integer
Dim intBoxCount As Integer
Dim intCurrentLevel As Integer
Dim intPreviousLevel As Integer
Dim intStartingLevel As Integer
Dim intHWMLevel As Integer
Dim lngPreviousStart As Long
Dim objDocument As Word.Document
Dim rng As Word.Range
Dim san As Office.SmartArtNode
Dim sanl(9) As Office.SmartArtNode
Dim shp As Word.InlineShape

bContinue = True
' set the range to the first paragraph in the containing Document
Set objDocument = rngLocation.Parent
Set rng = objDocument.Content.GoTo(wdGoToHeading, wdGoToFirst)
If headingLevel(rng) = 10 Then
  bContinue = False
Else
  bContinue = True
  lngPreviousStart = rng.Start
  While bContinue And (rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text <> (strTopLevelText & vbCr))
    Set rng = rng.GoToNext(wdGoToHeading)
    bContinue = (rng.Start <> lngPreviousStart)
    lngPreviousStart = rng.Start
  Wend
End If

If Not bContinue Then
  MsgBox "Could not find a Heading paragraph containing just the text """ & strTopLevelText & """", vbOKOnly
Else
  intStartingLevel = headingLevel(rng)
  intPreviousLevel = intStartingLevel
  bDiagramCreated = False
  Set rng = rng.GoToNext(wdGoToHeading)
  intCurrentLevel = headingLevel(rng)
  While (rng.Start > lngPreviousStart) And (intCurrentLevel > intStartingLevel)
    ' we have got one Heading with a lower level
    ' so start creating our hierarchy diagram
    If Not bDiagramCreated Then
      ' Create and empty the shape
      Set shp = rngLocation.InlineShapes.AddSmartArt(Application.SmartArtLayouts(strLayout), rngLocation)
      With shp.SmartArt
        For i = .AllNodes.Count To 1 Step -1
          .AllNodes(i).Delete
        Next
      End With
      Set sanl(intCurrentLevel) = shp.SmartArt.Nodes.Add
      intHWMLevel = intCurrentLevel
      bDiagramCreated = True
    Else
      If intCurrentLevel = intPreviousLevel Then
        Set sanl(intCurrentLevel) = sanl(intCurrentLevel).AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeAfter)
      Else
        If intCurrentLevel > intPreviousLevel Then
          For intLevel = intPreviousLevel + 1 To intCurrentLevel
            If Not (sanl(intLevel) Is Nothing) Then
              Set sanl(intLevel) = Nothing
            End If
            Set sanl(intLevel) = sanl(intLevel - 1).AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeBelow)
            If intLevel < intCurrentLevel Then
              With sanl(intLevel).TextFrame2.TextRange
                .Text = thePlaceholderText
                .Font.Name = theFontName
              End With
            End If
          Next
        Else ' higher level than previous
          If sanl(intCurrentLevel) Is Nothing Then
            Set sanl(intCurrentLevel) = sanl(intHWMLevel).AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeAfter)
          Else
            Set sanl(intCurrentLevel) = sanl(intCurrentLevel).AddNode(msoSmartArtNodeAfter)
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
    With sanl(intCurrentLevel).TextFrame2
      With .TextRange
         .Text = Left(rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, Len(rng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text) - 1)
         .Font.Name = "Arial"
      End With
    End With
    lngPreviousStart = rng.Start
    intPreviousLevel = intCurrentLevel
    Set rng = rng.GoToNext(wdGoToHeading)
    intCurrentLevel = headingLevel(rng)
  Wend
  If bDiagramCreated Then
    For intLevel = 1 To 9
      Set sanl(intLevel) = Nothing
    Next
    Set shp = Nothing
  Else
    MsgBox "No suitable headings found.", vbOKOnly
  End If
End If
skip:
Set rng = Nothing
Set objDocument = Nothing
End Sub


Function headingLevel(rng As Word.Range) As Integer
' looks at the first paragraph in Range rng
' returns 1 - 9 for heading styles 1 to 9, 10 for any other style
Dim d As Word.Document
Dim s As Word.Style
' AFAIK we have to assign a Style object, otherwise we
' just get a variant
With rng
  Set d = rng.Parent
  Set s = .Paragraphs(1).Style
  Select Case s.NameLocal
    Case d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading3).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading4).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading5).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading6).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading7).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading8).NameLocal, _
            d.Styles(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading9).NameLocal
        headingLevel = s.ListLevelNumber
      Case Else
        headingLevel = 10
  End Select
  Set s = Nothing
  Set d = Nothing
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I've never used macros in Word.  Could you maybe explain how to create one?  I am using Word 2010.

Comment: You will need to familiarise, but roughly: (1) if the Developer Tab is not enabled, enable it by Checking the relevant entry in the second column in File->Options->Customize Ribbon. (2) In the Ribbon, click the Developer tab, then the Visual Basic button. (3) In the Project window, select Normal, and click Insert->Module. (4) copy the code from my message and paste it into the newly created Module window. (5) after you have followed the instructions I gave, click somewhere in the testMakeHierarchy sub and press F5 (or click the "Run Sub" arrow icon in the standard toolbar in the VB Editor).

Comment: Ok, managed to run it but it is showing a message "Could not find a Heading paragraph...".  What do you mean by "It assumes that your headings are paragraphs that use the standard Heading Styles"?  I've created headings using the Styles > Heading 1-9.  Is this ok?

Comment: THat should be OK. Taking the outline you provided as an example, the idea is that you would have a Heading 1 style with the text "Project Information", then "Homepage", "Common Components" would be Heading 2,  "Interactive Banner" would be Heading 3, etc. You have to use the standard built-in Styles, and as things stand, the macro looks for the exact text, so no additional spaces, exactly the same capitalisation etc. If you have done all that and it still isn't picking up the hierarchy, there's probably an error in the code and I'll have a further look.

Comment: See http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm and http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/installing_employing_macros.html for help with macros.